# How do I correctly combine 2 script, so both are onEdit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know I've seen very similar questions asked, but none I've found so far fit where I'm stuck.
I originally had 3 scripts I wanted to combine. I attempted to combine 1 (and this has some weird issues, which I'll get to below***), and now have 2 scripts that I'd like to both be triggered by onEdit, but I can't seem to combine them correctly. The reason I assume is likely due to how the 2 scripts differ in their writing (which is also why a lot of the solutions I've found so far haven't solved it for me).

Here are the 2 scripts:

This one creates a functional checkbox based on criteria

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (e.value === "Tech Note" || 
        e.value === "Intake Process")
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),3).insertCheckboxes();
    else
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),3).removeCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

This one creates a master sheet of open action items from all the tabs
***This one got weird when I attempted to combine what it did for the "Tech" and "Intake" columns of "Open Action Items" tab, A3 & E3. It sorts some of the info at the top (rows 3-5), but then the info from "E03-O" sheet at the bottom (rows 51-55).
I did what I could to eliminate the empty rows, but wasn't able to get that down either. My work around was going to be sorting, but now this happened...

```
function myfunction() {
  
  //set variable
  const masterSheet = "Open Action Items";
  const mastersheetFormulaCell1 = "A3";
  const checkRange2 = "$J3:$J"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  let formulaArray1 = filteredListOfSheets.map(s => `iferror(FILTER('${s.getSheetName()}'!${dataRange1}, NOT(ISBLANK('${s.getSheetName()}'!${checkRange1}))),{"","",""})`);


  let formulaText1 = "=Sort({" + formulaArray1.join(";") + "},2, false)";
 
  ss.getSheetByName(masterSheet).getRange(mastersheetFormulaCell1).setFormula(formulaText1);

}
```

[**Here's an example sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Jd6Zm4VsxHAsRW29Dbm_0Nsmb0RjtP_8kmsl_1k0Kw/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help or guidance much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call myfunction(); in onEdit(e)

It helps to keep code organized if you write short functions and include them in the function you need them called.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2) {
    myfunction();
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (e.value === "Tech Note" || 
        e.value === "Intake Process")
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),3).insertCheckboxes();
    else
      sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(),3).removeCheckboxes();
  }
}
```

Comment: I placed the script you shared, and it didn't seem to work. Not sure what I'm missing. :/